# unar: symbol lookup error: unar: undefined symbol: main

Tags: raspbian

I installed `unar` from `apt-get`, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
unar: symbol lookup error: unar: undefined symbol: main
```

Even using `lsar` gives me the a similar error:

```
lsar: symbol lookup error: lsar: undefined symbol: main
```

I found on the internet it should be a linking error, but I cannot find how to fix it.

Comment: Try `ar x archive.a` instead of `unar` and `ar t archive.a`  instead of `lsar` and see if those work.

Comment: They work, but return the same error: `ar: archive.rar: File format not recognized`

Comment: How are `undefined symbol: main` and `File format not recognized` the same error?

Answer (score 1):

A [`.rar` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)) is compressed using [a proprietary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR_(file_format)); the problem with this is that FOSS tools which reverse engineer it will may end up behind  the curve if the people who distribute the proprietary versions (e.g. WinRAR) tweak it.

There's a `unrar-free` in Raspbian which apparently does not work for all files.  There's an `unrar-nonfree` in [Debian wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/unrar), but in [Raspbian](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/non-free/u/unrar-nonfree/) the actual binaries are missing; obviously they have not been compiled.  However, there is source for that in the `.orig.tar.gz` file.

Comment: Actually it seems like unar is able to cope with rar file since [version 0.99](http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline).

As for unrar-free I did try it, but it seems this rar's version is not supported.

I'd like not to use unrar (non-free).

Comment: Ah -- I didn't realize `unar` was more general purpose than `ar`.   See edits.

Comment: I solved compiling `unar` from source, it's working, do you know how I could help fixing raspbian repository?

Comment: You probably have to get a hold of whoever -- starting with [IRC](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianIRC) is probably the easiest way if you're familiar with that.

Comment: @imbalind Try `reportbug --file $(which unar)`. You might have to install `reportbug` first.